# How to read property value of a DIV which is set by a CSS class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a DIV with a class:

```
.myClass {
   width : 40px;
   height: 40px;
   display:block;
}
```

In HTML, I have declared:

```
<div class = "myClass"> Hello</div>
```

How can I read in JavaScript the value of the property "display" of this div?

I tried:

```
a = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")
console.log(a[0].style.display)
```

But I am not seeing anything in the Console.

Comment: `console.log(a[0].style.display)`

Comment: One problem is in `getElementsByClass()` that should be `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: `a.style.display` will return a value only if `display` is set using inline styles, more at [HTMLElement.style on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to calculate the "computed" style (the resulting style after applying all stylesheets.
This is done by calling [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0];
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('display');
console.log(style);
```

```css
.myClass {
   width : 40px;
   height: 40px;
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass"> Hello</div>
```

Comment: it works great, thank you! if you have time to help me with one last thing: what if i want to change the value of display property? I tried setPropertyValue('display', 'none') but it does not work.

Comment: Just the usual, `element.style.display = 'none'`.

Answer (score 2):

JQuery option:

```
$(".myClass").css("display")
```

```js
console.log($(".myClass").css("display"));
```

```css
.myClass {
   width : 40px;
   height: 40px;
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "myClass"> Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementByClass("youclass")[i].style.property = style
```

Note that `getElementByClass()` will return an array with the elements of that class so you need to give the index of the the element you want to change.